# TypeScript bug? `this` difference between `get` syntax and `defineProperty`'s `get`

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, getter, defineproperty

I have got this code:

```js
var x = {
  x1: 5,
  x2: 7
};

var y = {
  ...x,
  _originalX2: x.x2,
  get x2() {
    console.log(this.x1);
    return 9;
  }
};
console.log(y.x2);

var z = {
  ...x,
  _originalX2: x.x2
};
Object.defineProperty(z, 'x2', {
  get: function() {
    console.log(this.x1);
    return 9;
  }
})
console.log(z.x2);
```

When I run this as JavaScript in the browser or in NodeJS, I get the output:

```
5
9
5
9
```

When I run the same code as TypeScript (see https://repl.it/repls/TornHomelyThing), I get the output:

```
undefined
9
5
9
```

I also see what JS TS generates from it @ https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/G4QwTgBAHhC8EG8oEYBcECsAaaAmdA7AL4DcAUGaJAJ5yJkQQB0LUODEA+gPZgCWAcz4A7EABsAGvihMoudowEBTAC54AFAEoEHRgGNuwgM7cxSpmO4D1KgBZ8js5JvKNGYVQFcwwiAE5XCCIyUjIDY1NzS2tqWVwXCioIAC86HUYWWQUuXkERcSlUGTkQ8gB5ACMAKyU9FSYAEyUAMxElAAUwbgAHJTAVanVknAByORGcBAhlFXRmz2E6vkMtejcIcJMzCysbe0cUBPWPFW9fAI4iIM0wwy2o3eS4hKA .

My question is two-fold:

1. Is this to be considered a bug in TypeScript given that the same code in JS has different behavior?
2. Is there a good reason for the `this` not being able to reference the `x1` in the TypeScript generated JS? Or, is that a bug in JS itself?

Comment: It indeed seems to be a bug in the typescript compiler. Worth mentioning: if you set typescript target to `es2018` or newer it works just fine.

Comment: Yes it is check out the complied code from this typescript playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=11#code/G4QwTgBAHhC8EG8oEYBcECsAaaAmdA7AL4DcAUGaJAJ5yJkQQB0LUODEA+gPZgCWAcz4A7EABsAGvihMoudowEBTAC54AFAEoEHRgGNuwgM7cxSpmO4D1KgBZ8jOOw9nJN5RozCqArmGEQAJweEERkpGQGxqbmltbUsrjuFFQQAF50OowssgpcvIIi4lKoMnLh5ADyAEYAVkp6KkwAJkoAZiJKAApg3AAOSmAq1OppOADkcuM4CBDKKuhtPsKNfIZa9J4QUSZmFlY29kauyVveKn4BwRxEoZqRhruxB2mJyUA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this to be considered a bug in TypeScript given that the same code in JS has different behavior?

Yes, this definitely looks like a bug related to Typescript's transpilation of object spread syntax. The compiled TS is not doing the same thing as the JS.

In the first, you define a `y` object with a property `x2`, which is a getter:

```
var y = {
  ...x, 
  _originalX2:x.x2, 
  get x2(){
```

So referencing `y.x2` later results in the getter being invoked. But in the compiled Typescript, we get:

```js
var x = { x1: 5, x2: 7 };
var y = Object.assign(
  Object.assign({}, x),
  {
    _originalX2: x.x2,
    get x2() {
      console.log(this.x1);
    }
  }
);
```

This will result in the getter being invoked *immediately* - getters get invoked when in an object passed as the 2nd or more argument inside `Object.assign`. And when the getter is invoked, `this` refers to the second argument, this object here:

```
{
  _originalX2: x.x2,
  get x2() {
    console.log(this.x1);
  }
}
```

Which does not have an `x1` property, thus it logs `undefined`.

The `undefined` is logged *before* the `Object.assign` finishes, before you get to the next line of `console.log(y.x2);`.

For a more minimal example:

```
var y = {
  ...{}, 
  get prop(){
    console.log('should not be invoked immediately');
  }
};
```

gets incorrectly transpiled to

```
var y = Object.assign({}, { get prop() {
        console.log('should not be invoked immediately');
    } });
```

If you make it so that Typescript *doesn't* transpile object spread syntax, by bumping the target past ES2017, it'll work. For example, with ESNext, the above gets transpiled to:

```
var y = {
    ...{},
    get prop() {
        console.log('should not be invoked immediately');
    }
};
```

Comment: Found an existing TS bug for this @ https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24799 .